# Is there a way to model relationships only by url?

Tags: jsdata

Let's imagine we get this JSON from the server:

```
{
 id: 1,
 name: "John",
 comments: [{
  id: 1,
  comment: "some comment"
 }]
}
```

Now I'd like this answer to be parsed like this:

```
UserModel
   ---- has (0 to n) ---> CommentModel
```

I know that if I'd add userId to the comment and specify it as foreignKey in the hasMany relationship that it would work.

But I'm wondering, if it can be done without having a foreign key on the comment. I mean the relationship is quite obvious by the data itself with comments being an array on the user and its url being http://somehost/user/1/comment/1.

Comment: I think you should use a foreignKey on the comment, the idea is it will automatically inject comments and then you can manipulate them in the `comment` resource without the need to specify the user.

Comment: I came here with the same question. I'm not inclined to update our API, as this would require modifying nearly every endpoint. Good luck, I'll post here if I find anything out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the foreignKey on the comment in order for the nested comments to be auto-injected into the right part of the store, but you should still have the foreignKey defined in the relation definition so things like `loadRelations` will still work.

Comment: +1, exactly what I needed. I assumed I had to include either `localKey` or `foreignKey`, and couldn't figure out what to use for them. Never entered my mind to leave them out. Thanks!